# Google Drive API: check if folder exists

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API to try to answer a seemingly simple question: does a folder by a certain name exist in a drive?

Specifics:

- Version V3 of the drive API
- Python client: `googleapiclient`

Example:

Given the enclosing drive ID `abcdef`, does the folder with name `June 2019` (and mimeType `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`) exist?

Current route:

```
>>> from googleapiclient.discovery import build
>>> # ... build credentials
>>> driveservice = build("drive", "v3", credentials=cred).files()
>>> [i for i in driveservice.list().execute()['files'] if 
...  i['name'] == 'June 2019' and i['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder']                                                                                                                                                                     
[{'kind': 'drive#file',
  'id': '1P1k5c2...........',
  'name': 'June 2019',
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}]
```

So the answer is yes, the folder exists.  But there should be a more efficient way to do this [via `.list()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) by passing the `driveId`.  How can that be done?  I've tried various combinations all of which seem to throw a non-200 response.

```
>>> FOLDER_ID = "abcdef........"
>>> driveservice.list(corpora="drive", driveId=FOLDER_ID).execute()                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# 403 response, even when adding the additional requested params
```

How can I use the `q` param to query by folder name?

Answer (score 12):

When using `driveId` and `corpora="drive"`, you need to provide two more parameters: `includeItemsFromAllDrives` and `supportsAllDrives`

Code:

```py
response = driveservice.list(
    q="name='June 2019' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
    driveId='abcdef',
    corpora='drive',
    includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
    supportsAllDrives=True
).execute()

for item in response.get('files', []):
    # process found item
```

**Update:**

If it's a drive id you're sure exists and you keep getting "Shared drive not found" error, it might be a scope problem with credentials you've aquired for the api.
Also according to these Google API documents there seems to a lot of changes and deprecations happening, all related to the shared drives api support.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

If you keep having these problems, here's alternative solution for you using the `spaces` parameter:

```py
response = driveservice.list(
    q="name='June 2019' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
    spaces='drive'
).execute()

for item in response.get('files', []):
    # process matched item
```

Comment: From this I get `HttpError 404 when requesting ... "Shared drive not found: ...` even though the shared drive by that ID does exist. (See the last part of my question.)

Comment: Please take a look at the update to the answer and see if the alternative solution using the `spaces` parameter suits you needs.

Comment: Hey, did you try out the proposed solution, is it working or it's no good for your case?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this does not answer the question because it doesn't return whether the folder exists _in a certain drive_.  For an easy example, consider a scenario where two folders of the same name exist in different drives. This call will return two `drive#file` IDs.  The point here is to check within a specific location for the folder

Comment: (But I agree with you on the point that, holy crap is the Google Drive API confusing.)

Comment: Yeah I see. Google API's can be quite a pain most of the time.
Meanwhile I stumbled upon this article: https://medium.com/@stephane.giron/how-to-deal-with-google-drive-api-for-team-drive-some-apps-script-code-d8a78824485f
Check the paragraph named "Google Drive API v2 or v3 ?". It might be possible that this feature only works with v2, I might give this hint a try later and drop a line if something interesting comes up.